# Adam Optimizer is apparently not converging

Tags: machine-learning, rust, arrayfire

I am trying to write a neural network in rust + arrayfire, and while gradient descent works, ADAM does not.

```
fn back_propagate(
    &mut self,
    signals: &Vec<Array<f32>>,
    labels: &Array<u8>,
    learning_rate_alpha: f64,
    batch_size: i32,
) {
    let mut output = signals.last().unwrap();
    let mut error = output - labels;

    for layer_index in (0..self.num_layers - 1).rev() {
        let signal = Self::add_bias(&signals[layer_index]);
        let deriv = self.layer_activations[layer_index].apply_deriv(output);

        let delta = &(deriv * error).T();

        let matmul = matmul(&delta, &signal, MatProp::NONE, MatProp::NONE);
        let gradient_t = (matmul / batch_size).T();

        match self.optimizer {
            Optimizer::GradientDescent => {
                let weight_update = learning_rate_alpha * gradient_t;
                self.weights[layer_index] -= weight_update;
            }
            Optimizer::Adam => {
                let exponents = constant(2f32, gradient_t.dims());

                self.first_moment_vectors[layer_index] = (&self.beta1[layer_index]
                    * &self.first_moment_vectors[layer_index])
                    + (&self.one_minus_beta1[layer_index] * &gradient_t);

                self.second_moment_vectors[layer_index] = (&self.beta2[layer_index]
                    * &self.second_moment_vectors[layer_index])
                    + (&self.one_minus_beta2[layer_index]
                        * arrayfire::pow(&gradient_t, &exponents, true));

                let corrected_first_moment_vector = &self.first_moment_vectors[layer_index]
                    / &self.one_minus_beta1[layer_index];

                let corrected_second_moment_vector = &self.second_moment_vectors[layer_index]
                    / &self.one_minus_beta2[layer_index];

                let denominator = sqrt(&corrected_second_moment_vector) + 1e-8;
                let weight_update =
                    learning_rate_alpha * (corrected_first_moment_vector / denominator);

                self.weights[layer_index] -= weight_update;
            }
        }

        output = &signals[layer_index];

        let err = matmulTT(
            &delta,
            &self.weights[layer_index],
            MatProp::NONE,
            MatProp::NONE,
        );

        error = index(&err, &[seq!(), seq!(1, output.dims()[1] as i32, 1)]);
    }
}
```

I've stored beta1, beta2, 1-beta1, 1-beta2 in constant arrays for every layer just to avoid having to recompute them. It appears to have made no difference.

GradientDescent converges with a learning rate alpha=2.0, however with Adam, if i use alpha>~0.02, the network appears to get locked in. Funnily enough, if I remove all the hidden layers, it does work. Which tells me something, but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, for anyone else, my alpha=0.01 is still too high, once I reduced it to 0.001, it converged very quickly